# I can't right align a div correctly inside a div that automatically centers

Tags: html, css

I recently decided to make a change to a div (#BG) which automatically keeps it horizontally centered with a css rule:

margin:25px auto 0 auto

Unfortunately this also makes other divs (#nextBtnBG and #nextBtn) inside of it not align to the right like it used to. If I make the window wider it changes the position, because it is anchored to the left or right side of the window inside of the div #BG.

```
<div id="BG">

    <div id='slideHolder'>
        <img id='slide' class="centerSlide" src="img/1.png" alt="" />
        <div onclick="prevSlide(event)" id="prevBtnBG">
            <div onclick="prevSlide(event)" id="prevBtn"><</div>
        </div>
        <div onclick="nextSlide(event)" id="nextBtnBG">
            <div onclick="nextSlide(event)" id="nextBtn">></div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

So #slide is an image and the previous and next buttons are supposed to float on top of it, and it's why it uses an absolute position. #prevBtnBG and #prevBtn work fine. It's #nextBtnBG and #nextBtn that are the problems.

My CSS:

```
#prevBtnBG {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    width:250px;
    height:720px;
    background-color: rgba(90, 90, 90, 0.2);
}

#prevBtn {
    color:white;
    font-size: 80px;
    position: relative;
    top: 310px;
    left: 105px;
    cursor: default;
}

#nextBtnBG {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 250px;
    width:250px;
    height:720px;
    background-color: rgba(90, 90, 90, 0.2);
}

#nextBtn {
    color:white;
    font-size: 80px;
    position: relative;
    top: 310px;
    right: 105px;
    cursor: default;
}

#BG {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 800px;
    border: 0px solid black;
    margin: 25px auto 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to figure out your `position` attribute.

If you have elements positioned absolutely based on the parent, the parent should be `position: relative;`.

Also, you're using absolute positioning on an element in a container. (the buttons inside the background)

Answer (score 1):

try relative

```
#BG {
   position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below html and css code.

HTML:

```
<div id="BG">
            <div id='slideHolder'>
                <div class="centerSlide">
                    <img id='slide' src="images/1.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div onclick="prevSlide(event)" id="prevBtnBG">
                    <div onclick="prevSlide(event)" id="prevBtn"><</div>
                </div>
                <div onclick="nextSlide(event)" id="nextBtnBG">
                    <div onclick="nextSlide(event)" id="nextBtn">></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#BG {
        max-width: 1280px;
        height: 100vh;
        border: 0px solid black;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
        img{
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        #slideHolder{
            position: relative;
        }
        #prevBtnBG,
        #nextBtnBG{
            position: absolute;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 30px;
            width: 12%;
        }
        #prevBtnBG{
            left: 0;
        }
        #nextBtnBG{
            right: 0;
        }
        #prevBtn,
        #nextBtn{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
            cursor: default;
        }
        .centerSlide{
            line-height: 0;
        }
```

Comment: Could you explain your code some, other than just dumping it and saying use this.

Comment: Here I give the position relative  to parent div #slideHolder and give position absolute to next and previous button  in this example you can show #prevBtnBg and #nextBtnBg css  and for #prevBtnBg want to left align so you can use left:0  and #nextBtnBg want right align so you can use right:0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to right align any element, use this in the tag : `style="float: right;"`.